# how to rewrite the url in lowercase in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I have a gateway URL: https://baseurl/1.0.0/Api/Users/Login
and require to rewrite in lower case using URLRewrite Mediator.

Require to navigate here: https://baseurl/1.0.0/api/users/login
What should I set in value, type and fragment attributes.

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriterule>
      <action value="tolowercase{url}" type="set" fragment="path"/>
  </rewriterule>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of URL rewrite mediator, you can easily get this done with property mediator.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="NewAPI:v1.0.0--In">
    <property name="URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('axis2','REST_URL_POSTFIX')" />
    <property name="URL_POSTFIX_LOWER_CASE" expression="lower-case(get-property('URL_POSTFIX'))"/>
    <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('URL_POSTFIX_LOWER_CASE')" scope="axis2" />
</sequence>
```

Comment: I have not tried yet because it require adding an integration layer. WSO2 guy is not recommending this. Since it is in my low priority. Just to achieve lower case URL, it will effect performance? What do you say on this.

Comment: I don't think this logic alone will have that much of a performance loss. but it can effect if you have path parameters and they will too be converted to lower case.

Comment: we are not giving parameters in URL ( like query string etc. baseurl/res?id=xyz), and sending data in POST calls. Data will be retrieved from body. In that way, this logic will not give much performance loss. Right?

Comment: Yeah. If you need, you can check the round trip time with and without this mediation sequence and there shouldn't be much performance impact. This is a very simple mediation logic compared to other sequences.